# Continuity properties of an isosurface of a continuous function in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given continuous (say $\mathcal C^2$) function 
$f: \mathbb R^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ what could be continuity properties for an isosurface of such a function (of each of its disjoint components)?
Can we expect it to be same ($\mathcal C^2$) continuous?

*It seems easy to prove for $\mathcal C^0$, but I afraid to miss some nuances -  multidimensionality often gives surprises.*

Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: Consider $f(x,y) = y^2 - x^3$.  The level surface $f=1$ is smooth, but $f=0$ is not.  So it depends not just on $f$, but on the level value.

Comment: I got confused a bit with my answer, now deleted, but I don't understand how. I think informally I'm missing that isosurfaces define implicit functions usually, at least locally.

Comment: What's your position on the continuity of self-intersections?

Comment: @EricTowers -- I assumed a single-valued function in $R^n$. This function can be regarded as a surface without self-intersections in $R^{n+1}$. Isosurfaces of this function in $R^n$ are its level surfaces in $R^{n+1}$. I think that the only origin of self-intersections can be when such level surface has disjoint components, which I believe can not self-intersect and cannot intersect each other but only can be adjoined. In latter case adjoined continuous surfaces (of same dimension) still, I believe, comprise a continuous self-intersecting surface (continuous along any path). Am I right?

Comment: Let $f(x) = \left(\mathrm{dist}(x, P)\right)^2$ where $P$ is the symbol $+$ lying somewhere in the plane and $\mathrm{dist}$ returns the infimum of the distances between $x$ and $P$.  The zero level set is $P$ and is self-intersecting.  In fact, you can let $P$ be any finite set of rectifiable curves in the plane.  For more examples, see elliptic curves as the parameters pass values producing singular curves -- this only requires $f$ to be the projection onto the "$z$" coordinate to produce cusps and self-intersections.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang – Thank you, that answers my question. Soberingly. So often fails to deduce specific properties from generic ones. I will have to reformulate my real problem in more specific terms. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EricTowers -- See, right. Looks like again I assumed something more specific than what I declared, in this case, some kind of a function expressed in an analytical form. Thank you very much.